# Zipping (Archive Utility) in 10.14.6 using other sorting order than Finder

Tags: zip, archive-utility

As of macOS 10.14.6 (maybe since 10.14.0) I noticed that when I zip files directly within Finder (Select files, right click, compress) that the resulting Archive.zip contains the selected files but in another order than shown in Finder. 
Sort order in finder: alphabetically (by Name, ascending).
Sort order in zip: i don't know what order it has...

How can I set the sort order in ZIPs back to alphabetically?

Screenshots:

1) This is the order in the Finder:

[image]

2) This is the order in the ZIP file when using macOS 10.14.6 compression (select all, right click, compress):
So the order is 4 - 2 - 3 - 1 (instead of 1 - 2 - 3 - 4)

[image]

3) Here is the order in the ZIP file when using KeKa:
[image]

I hope my question is clear now and we can avoid unnecessary "why is this important" comments... Thanks!

Comment: I guess,  the destination would have a different sort order, instead of the zip itself. I see zips as just carriers.

Comment: In some cases, sort order within the ZIP is important. I'm not talking about any issue on the destination system, I'm seeing this on my local Mac Pro. In macOS 10.13. the sort order form Finder was preserved in the resulting ZIP.

Comment: What are you using to see inside the zip?

Comment: I meant destination folder. But if you say it's important, I've starred it. Will revisit.

Comment: In which cases is sort order within a ZIP file important?

Comment: @Tetsujin: Terminal: `unzip -l filename.zip` (when I zip with KeKa, the sort order is still good, when using the MacOS Compressor (Archive Utility, right-click out of Finder), the sort order is wrong.

Comment: Once it's back in the Finder, then sort order is going to be whatever you have selected for that window. I've tested macOS built-in compressor & then checked the index numbers in BetterZip. They are correct.

Comment: @nohillside : is this important? there are several use cases I can think of. Example: a program, that extracts the files from a ZIP content must begin with the "first" file in the ZIP. And in some cases it might be important that the first is the first as seen originally in the Finder...

Comment: I'm with nohillside on 'why is it important?' I think if your use-case is dependant on any kind of race condition, you need to change your use-case.

Comment: @Testujin: Yes, I know, thanks. Of course if you extract the files are again sorted in Finder. I'm talking about the sort order at extraction time, so the first file being extracted is NOT the first as initially seen in the Finder. Also, the destination system might not be a Mac with a Finder but any other backend software doing the extraction and processing on each file.

Comment: @Tetsujin: I'm not having a race condition, i'm talking simply about the sort order IN THE ZIP FILE. I think you just don't know the answer and want the change the question now ;-)

Comment: Perhaps if I stick my beak in @basZero: **IN DETAIL** explain why the order inside the zip file is in any way important. If you need "the first item" to be unzipped first, **WHY?** We are not being argumentative but if we understand all of the reasons (other than "it offends my sense of order") then we can figure out (at least) an alternative.

Comment: I added some screenshots to make my question clear. I have an alternative already myself (using KeKa), but still, I wonder why Apple has changed the archiving utility and maybe others have the same question as I do, irrelevant with regards to usecase details and "WHY"-questions. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Questions: 1. Did you actually look at the indexes yet? 2. What command are you using to see the contents & their ordering in Terminal?

Comment: @basZero "And in some cases it might be important that the first is the first as seen originally in the Finder": That's exactly what we are wondering about here. In which cases is it important? Also, even in Finder, the order of files on disk may differ from what you see within a Finder window. So overall sort order is arbitrary and doesn't reflect the physical order on disk.

Comment: Per the [ZIP file specification](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT)

`4.3.3 Files MAY be stored in arbitrary order within a ZIP file.` and `4.4.1.3  The entries in the central directory MAY NOT necessarily be in the same order that files appear in the .ZIP file.`  You might just be seeing implementation details.

Comment: @vykor: thanks for the link to the ZIP specification. However I didn't say that my zipping usecase has a bug or alike, I was just observing this behaviour and wondered why it changed (the macOS Archive Utility zipped in alphabetical order since I use Mac... now it doesn't zip alphabetically anymore). It's ok, I only wonder.